# Prisma - How to group children together in self-relation query

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I'm having a following model in my schema:

```
model Collection {
  id         String       @id @default(cuid())
  title      String
  createdAt  DateTime     @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime     @updatedAt
  parent     Collection?  @relation("CollectionChildren", fields: [parentId], references: [id])
  parentId   String?
  children   Collection[] @relation("CollectionChildren")
}
```

What I have is a self-relation of collections. They can have unlimited levels.
Now, I want to query and order and list them so that the final result looks like this:

- Collection 1
- Collection 2

  - Collection 2 Child 1
  - Collection 2 Child 2
  - Collection 2 Child 3
- Collection 3

  - Collection 3 Child 1

    - Collection 3 Child 1 Sub-child 1
  - Collection 3 Child 2
  - Collection 3 Child 3
- Collection 4

The problem is that I have no idea how to query then so that they are ordered by title, while also grouped by parent.

Is that even possible in Prisma/Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to get all the children without knowing the depth of the levels of children (as you mentioned that there could be unlimited levels).

Prisma has a feature request to Support recursive relationships [#3725](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3725)

As a workaround, you would need to use [Raw Query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access).

The SQL query could look something like this:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE collection_tree AS (
  SELECT id, title, parentId
  FROM Collection
  WHERE parentId IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.title, c.parentId
  FROM Collection c
  JOIN collection_tree ct ON ct.id = c.parentId
)
SELECT *
FROM collection_tree
ORDER BY title;
```

This query uses a recursive CTE to first select the top-level collections (where the `parentId` is `null`), and then select all the children of those collections by joining the `collection_tree` CTE with the Collection table on the `parentId`. The result is a flattened list of all the collections and their children, ordered by the title field.

Comment: Thanks @nurul-sundarani Unfortunately, the query does not work for me. It returns all collections ordered by title only. Any idea what could be wrong here?